# Rails migration change field in table

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

So I generated a migration to change the `:comments` of my Reviews table from string to text.

```
class ChangeDataTypeForReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :reviews do |t|
      t.change :comments, :text
    end
  end
  def self.down
    change_table :reviews do |t|
      t.change :comments, :string
    end
  end
end
```

After running rake `db:migrate`, it worked and did change it to text, but I was wondering why in my actual `createReviews` migration, comments is still a string, and does this matter, or should I change it to text?

```
   class CreateReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :reviews do |t|
          t.string :artist
          t.string :comments

          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you have run this,

```
class ChangeDataTypeForReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :reviews do |t|
      t.change :comments, :text
    end
  end
  def self.down
    change_table :reviews do |t|
      t.change :comments, :string
    end
  end
end
```

after executing,

```
  class CreateReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :reviews do |t|
        t.string :artist
        t.string :comments

        t.timestamps
      end
    end
  end
```

So, the latest change will be reflected in the corresponding table. It will not change anything in the previously created migration file. I.e., why we call it as `Migration`, right?

So, no need to change `t.string :comments`, because with the latest migration, we did change the datatype to `text`. So, it will always be interpreted as a `text type` field only.

Go through [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) properly.

Hope it helps :)